# Wordpress Widget Development - Width increases when opening

Tags: widget, width, wordpress

On the Wordpress widgets page you can see that some widgets' width increases when you click/toggle them in the sidebar. How can I do that with my own widgets? I'm using the WP_Widget class.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you register the widget you can set the widget control options, which enables to control the width.

Check the following sample code:

```
<?php
class WP_Widget_Text_Link extends WP_Widget {

    function WP_Widget_Text_Link() {
        $widget_ops = array('classname' => 'widget_text', 'description' => __('Arbitrary text or HTML with Title linked'));
        $control_ops = array('width' => 600, 'height' => 350);
        $this->WP_Widget('textlink', __('Text with Link'), $widget_ops, $control_ops);
    }

    // stripped down remaining code for the widget, which are not needed for the answer.
}
```